# AWS S3 JavaScript SDK - NetworkingError: Network Failure

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to use the examples provided by AWS in their Examples in the Browser webpage, and I keep receiving the `NetworkingError: Network Failure` error. Here is what I am using:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.0.0-rc11.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  // See the Configuring section to configure credentials in the SDK

  AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: '####', secretAccessKey: '####', region: 'us-east-1'});
  // Configure your region
//  AWS.config.region = '';
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="file" id="file-chooser" />
<button id="upload-button">Upload to S3</button>
<div id="results"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var bucket = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'BUCKETNAMEGOESHERE'}});

  var fileChooser = document.getElementById('file-chooser');
  var button = document.getElementById('upload-button');
  var results = document.getElementById('results');
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var file = fileChooser.files[0];
    if (file) {
      results.innerHTML = '';

      var params = {Key: file.name, ContentType: file.type, Body: file};
      bucket.putObject(params, function (err, data) {
        results.innerHTML = err ? err : 'UPLOADED.';
      });
    } else {
      results.innerHTML = 'Nothing to upload.';
    }
  }, false);
</script>

<div id="status"></div>
<ul id="objects"></ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var bucket = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'BUCKETNAMEGOESHERE'}});
  bucket.listObjects(function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Could not load objects from S3';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Could not load objects from S3';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Loaded ' + data.Contents.length + ' items from S3';
      for (var i = 0; i < data.Contents.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById('objects').innerHTML +=
          '<li>' + data.Contents[i].Key + '</li>';
      }
    }
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My bucket is in the US Standard region, and I am trouble figuring out whether it uses `us-west-2` or `us-east-1`. When I go to my bucket's console, the URL is `https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/home?region=us-west-2` yet someone mentioned on here that US Standard is `us-east-1`.

Comment: US standard is `us-east-1`

Answer (score 7):

This error occurs because you don't set the CORS configuration.

1. Open the Amazon S3 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/.
2. Select the name of the bucket you are using from the bucket list.
3. Next, Choose "Permission" tab.
4. Then in an editor titled "Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)", you need to make sure the S3 bucket has following CORS configuration:

---

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "HEAD",
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "ETag"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: As tempting and as easy this makes things, just remember this would cause security issues, because you're letting anyone from any source origin to be able to perform all of these actions on your bucket, which in turn will affect your S3 price.

Answer (score 3):

As of the writing of this answer, according to the [Amazon Web Services General Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html), US Standard uses `us-east-1`.

Answer (score 2):

This is really late but if anyone else stumbles over this you need to make sure your CORS file in console has sufficient permissions.

Comment: @VMTrooper can you please share you CROS here. Thanks