# Network error when downloading file from S3 - NextJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, amazon-s3, next.js

I am trying to download a file from Amazon S3, but the call is giving me network error. I have setup my amazon config file accordingly to need and I am using S3.getObjectURl() method to download it. Unfortunately it fails. Here is my code:

```
export const AWSDownload = (link = '') => {
  const s3 = new AWS.S3({endpoint: 's3Url',region: 'us-east-1',accessKeyId: AWS_Config.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, secretAccessKey:AWS_Config.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY})

  const params = {
    Bucket: AWS_Config.AWS_BUCKET,
    Key: `${link}`
  }

  const handleDownload = () => {
    return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log('Handling download called')
      s3.getObject(params, (err, data:any) => {
        console.log(data, 'response')

        if (err) {
          console.log(err, err.stack)
          reject(err)
        } else {
          if (data.Body) {
            let binary = ''
            const bytes:any = new Uint8Array(data.Body)
            const len:any = bytes.byteLength
            for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
              binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i])
            }
            const b64encoded = `data:${data.ContentType};base64,${btoa(binary)}`
            resolve(b64encoded)
          } else {
            reject('Empty body')
          }
        }
      })
    })
  }

  return {
    downloadImage: handleDownload
  }
}

export const AWS_Config = {
  FILESYSTEM_DRIVER: 's3',
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: 'KeyID',
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: 'Secret Access Key',
  AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: 'us-east-1',
  AWS_BUCKET: 'Bucket'
}
```

The result is mentioned below:
[image: Network failed when downloading image from S3]

Comment: And have you searched for any info about the error message? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492735/aws-s3-javascript-sdk-networkingerror-network-failure
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21939010/how-can-i-avoid-networking-error-network-failure-when-downloading-a-file-from

Comment: I have, but didn't find appropriate solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the latest S3 client via:

```
import { S3Client, PutObjectCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3'
const s3Client = new S3Client({ region: process.env.region })
try {
    const data = await s3Client.send(new PutObjectCommand(uploadParams))
    console.log('Success', data)
} catch (err) {
    console.log('Error', err)
}
```

or check your network connection

**Edit:** Similarly look for getObjectCommand in the latest [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/classes/getobjectcommand.html) and implement it.